# The Relationship between Matrix and Its Share of Column & Share of Rows

Tags: matrices, geometry, matrix-calculus

Suppose I have a Matrix here, if you add up all the cells, it equal to $1$.

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
 0.4167 & 0.0833 \\ 
 0.0833 & 0.04167 \\ 
 0.125 & 0.25 
\end{pmatrix}$

Then, we know the share of rows (add up the row/column ) are $Row=(0.5,0.125,0.375)$ and the share of columns are $Column=(0.625,0.375)$.

Now, if we calculate:

$B= Row'*Column =\begin{pmatrix} 
 0.3125 & 0.1875 \\ 
 0.078125 & 0.046875 \\ 
 0.234375 & 0.140625 
\end{pmatrix}$

We see Matrix A is not equal to Matrix B, but they can all create the same row share and column share. But the row share & column share can only create Matrix B. The relationship is $A\rightarrow ROW/Column \leftrightarrow B$

My question is whether we have any method to figure out all the A (I mean all the combinations, maybe $A_1$ $A_2$) if we have a Matrix B. And can we know the number of A? Does it countable?

Thank you!

---

Here is the edition of the second time, because I figure out some of the problems.

If we transform the question into a Matrix calculation:

Let's define the matrix A, B has i columns and j rows: $A_{ij}$ $B_{ij}$  , and $p_{j1}$ $q_{1i}$ is the vector that every cell equal to 1.

The problem is

\begin{cases}
A_{ij} * p_{j1} = B_{ij} * p_{j1} \\
q_{1i} * A_{ij} = q_{1i} * B_{ij}
\end{cases}

Then:

\begin{cases}
(A_{ij}-B_{ij})  * p_{j1} = 0 \\
q_{1i} * (A_{ij}-B_{ij})  = 0
\end{cases}

If we make $T_{ij} = A_{ij}-B_{ij}$ ,

\begin{cases}
T_{ij}  * p_{j1} = 0 \\
q_{1i} * T_{ij}  = 0
\end{cases}

We are actually trying to find $T_{ij}$, which is obviously countless and continuous.

So, my question here is how to generate $T_{ij}$ matrix satisfied the equations, any algorithm or any paper discussing it's properties?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be a matrix of all ones, the same size as $A$, then the *expected value* of $A$ is
$$B = {\mathbb E}(A) = \frac{AN^TA}{{\rm Tr}(AN^T)}$$
The matrix $B$ preserves the marginal totals (row and column sums) of $A$, and there are an infinite number of different $A$ matrices with the same expected value $\,{\mathbb E}(A)$.

Given 
$$\eqalign{
&\lambda \in{\mathbb R},\quad
e_i\in{\mathbb R}^{m},\quad
\varepsilon_k\in{\mathbb R}^{n},\quad
A\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times n} \cr
}$$
where $\,\{e_i,\,\varepsilon_k\}$ are the standard basis vectors for their respective dimension.

Define the matrix
$$\eqalign{
&G_{hijk} = (e_h-e_i)(\varepsilon_j-\varepsilon_k)^T\quad {\rm e.g.}\quad
G_{1312}=\pmatrix{\;\;1&-1\\\;\;0&\;\;0\\-1&\;\;1}
}$$
Note that $N^TG_{hijk}=0\,$ and $\,G_{hijk}N^T=0$.

Finally, the family of matrices 
$$\eqalign{
F &= A + \lambda\,G_{hijk} \cr
}$$
has the same expected value for any combination of 
$\big\{h,i,j,k,\lambda\big\}$.

In particular, $\lambda=0\,$ recovers $A$.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's really an impressive answer!

Comment: This [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4668469) is cleaner.