# Comparative statics in linear programming

Tags: matrices, optimization, linear-programming

Suppose $\Phi$ is a $3 \times 3$ non-negative matrix and let $\mu(\Phi)$ be a solution to the following maximization problem over a nonnegative matrix,

$$\begin{aligned}
\max_{(\mu_{ij}) \geq 0}& &&\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \mu_{ij} \Phi_{ij} \\
\text{subject to}& &&\sum_{j=1}^3 \mu_{ij} = m_i &\forall i = 1, 2, 3\\
& &&\sum_{i=1}^3 \mu_{ij} = n_j &\forall j = 1, 2, 3
\end{aligned}
$$
where $m_i, n_j \geq 0$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 m_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^3 n_j = 1$.

I'm trying to understand how (generically unique) $\mu(\Phi)$ changes when I increase $\Phi_{11}$. My conjecture is, $\mu_{11}(\Phi)$ increases while $\mu_{12}(\Phi), \mu_{13}(\Phi), \mu_{21}(\Phi), \mu_{31}(\Phi)$ decrease. Is there any way to show this formally?

Comment: Where is the "doubly-stochastic" part?

Comment: Have you tried formulating the LP in a more "compressed" form using, say, matrix notation?

Comment: Please just replace "doubly-stochastic" with "non-negative"

Comment: Why use Greek letters?

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\l{\lambda} \def\e{\varepsilon} \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\size#1{\op{size}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$I'll use the uppercase letters $\{M,P\}$ instead of $\{\mu,\Phi\}\:$ to denote the matrix variables, and lowercase letters to denote vectors.
And instead of the $(3\times 3)$ case, consider the general $(m\times n)$ case.

Let $\left\{e_j\in\bbR m,\;\e_k\in\bbR n\right\}$ denote the standard orthonormal basis vectors for each dimension.

Start with a matrix $\left\{M\in\bbR{m\times n}\right\}$
which satisfies the non-negativity and row/col marginal constraints.

If we wish to change $M_{ij}$ by $\l$ then we must also change components in other rows/columns to maintain the marginal constraints. This idea is captured by the following parameterized matrix
$$\eqalign{
H_{ijkl} = \LR{e_i-e_k}\LR{\e_j-\e_l}^T \quad{\rm e.g.}\quad
 H_{1132} = \m{1&-1&0\\0&0&0\\-1&1&0}  \\
}$$
Notice that the row/column sums for $H_{ijkl}$ matrix are identically zero.

Therefore updating the matrix using
$$\eqalign{
M' &= M + \l H_{ijkl} \\
}$$
will automatically satisfy the marginal constraints for **any** combination of the $\{\l,i,j,k,l\}$ parameters.

Of course, you must also be careful when subtracting that you don't violate the non-negativity constraint.