# Parameterizing matrices whose rows and columns sum to a constant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, metric-spaces, nonlinear-optimization

I have a constrained optimization problem for a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. The objective doesn't matter, and the constraint is that
for some scalars $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
\begin{cases}
A_{i,j} &\ge 0, \forall i, j \\
\sum_{j=1}^n A_{i,j} &= \alpha, \forall i \\
\sum_{i=1}^m A_{i,j} &= \beta, \forall j \\
\end{cases}
$$

If there are only the nonnegativity and row sum constraints, I can use the parameterization $A = \operatorname{Softmax}(B)$ where $B$ is any matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and it reduces to an unconstrained optimization problem. However, the additional column sum constraint makes everything hard.

How can I parameterize $A$ as an unconstrained matrix?

Comment: Summing over the whole matrix produces $m$ for the first constraint, and $n$ for the second. These constraints are inconsistent unless $m=n.\;$

Comment: @greg You are right. I have edited the question. Each row and column must sum to a constant, but not necessarily the same constant.

Comment: The [Sinkhorn algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06349) can generate matrices which satisfy such constraints, so in theory you could replace $A={\sf Softmax}(B)$ with $A={\sf Sinkhorn}(B)$  This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3304446) may also be of interest.

Comment: The sum of the entries of $A$ must be equal to both $m\alpha$ and $n\beta$, so one must have $m\alpha=n\beta$. If $m=n$, then it follows that $\alpha=\beta$, and then the all-$1$s vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ would be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\alpha$.